# feature file in behave(BDD) throws an error

Tags: automated-testing, python, cucumber, bdd, behave

I have create a feature file and step definition file, to execute by test cases using behave (BDD ), but i am facing one error, when i execute the feature file, Please find below to check by code :-

first_behave.feature

```
Feature: My First behave feature

  Scenario: Add two numbers
    Given : I have two integers a and b
    When : I add the Numbers
    Then : I print the addition result
```

environement.py

```
from selenium import webdriver

def before_all(context):
     print("Executing before all")

def before_feature(context, feature):
     print("Before feature\n")

#Scenario level objects are popped off context when scenario exits
def before_scenario(context,Scenario):
    context.browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    print("Before scenario\n")

def after_scenario(context,scenario):
    context.browser.quit()
    print("After scenario\n")

def after_feature(context,feature):
     print("\nAfter feature")

def after_all(context):
     print("Executing after all")
```

first_behave.py

```
from behave import *
use_step_matcher("re")

@given("I have two integers a and b")
def step_impl(context):
    context.a = 1
    context.b = 2


@when("I add the Numbers")
def step_impl(context):
    context.sum = int(context.a) + int(context.b)


@then("I print the addition result")
def step_impl(context):
    print("Sum of", context.a, "and", context.b, "is: ", context.sum
```

and below is the error, i am facing:

> [0806/114406.139:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(690)] eglInitialize D3D9 failed with er
>   ror EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
>   [0806/114406.140:ERROR:gl_initializer_win.cc(240)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOf
>   f failed.
>   [0806/114406.161:ERROR:gpu_child_thread.cc(174)] Exiting GPU process due to erro
>   rs during initialization
>   [6120:5660:0806/114406.273:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(103)] Faile
>   d to launch GPU process.
>   Before scenario

Please help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example feature does not use the browser, but your code does:

```
context.browser = webdriver.Chrome()
```

The error you are getting is from Chrome, not from your test. For some reason the hardware acceleration is giving issues.

I would try the following things:

- Remove the webdriver code as your example does not need it.
- Update Chrome, the chromedriver and your operating system to the latest versions.
- Add the `--use-gl=desktop` as an argument for starting Chrome to disable hardware-acceleration. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698843/how-do-i-pass-options-to-the-selenium-chrome-driver-using-python) for how-to do that with python.

Now I am typing this I am wondering if you system has a GPU. You are not working on a virtual machine without hardware 3d-acceleration, are you? Probably you are.

Comment: Thank you Niels, for helping me.. You are right, it was a browser issue, i am using 32 bit chrome, in this one it didn't work. But  when i tried to execute it on 64 bit browser, it worked perfectly.. Thank you for the quick reply..